# Make Levnovo Yoga 710 touch screen functional Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: lenovo, touchscreen

I've done a lot of googling, and haven't found a good answer on this.  Has anyone had any success with Lenovo or similar on this?  I'm a huge newbie with all this, be gentle!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same configuration: Ubuntu 16.04 on Yoga 710. Unfortunately, Ubuntu 16.04 by default ships with Linux kernel 4.4 which does not have the required drivers to support Yoga 710 touchscreen.

All you need to do is update your kernel to 4.7 or higher and that should fix your problem. The procedure to upgrade your linux kernel is provided in a number of useful guides online. I followed the steps here:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/07/install-linux-kernel-4-7-ubuntu-16-04/

I can confirm that if done properly it should work normally for above configuration, but as advised in the website kernel upgrades can also have other effects! So be careful (Of course you can revert back to the old kernel from the boot menu in GRUB if things go wrong)

About the touchscreen support itself, It isn't as smooth as in Windows 10, **yet**! And you may have to customize the icons/ screen resolution etc. to make your UI touchscreen friendly. Unity Tweak Tool is a good place to start with!

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have the same setup with Lenovo Yoga 710 running Ubuntu 16.04. I have managed to make it decent with the help of a autorotate program from https://github.com/kkrizka/autorotate. It is not though I have not found an good solution for a touch interface in tablet mode...